# Encrypt your hard disk in C#

Tags: encryption, c#-4.0

How to secure a hard disk programmatically through C#?

Like if a user wants to open a hard disk and first he/she has to give a password to access it. If the password is wrong then the hard disk is hidden from that user..

Comment: We will not write your program for you.

Comment: If you're asking like this, you probably aren't qualified to handle sensitive data.  Good crypto is hard.

Comment: This isn't something that's easily done; it may even be impossible to do in pure C#. I'd suggest that your users download TrueCrypt or take a look at EFS instead. http://www.truecrypt.org/ http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encrypting_File_System

Comment: What do you mean by "open harddisk" anyway?  In your application, or in Windows Explorer, or in a command prompt...?

Comment: Voting to reopen. Not the greatest question but good enough, and the answers to it are also appropriate.

Comment: @SLaks: Good crypto is hard, but no one is barred from trying, from asking questions, making mistakes, and learning.

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to do this inside an app written in C#:

Get logical drives:

```
string[] drives = Directory.GetLogicalDrives();
```

Also check this out:
http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/C_Sharp/Q_23825199.html

http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/276247-get-drive-letter-win32_diskdrive

You'll need to expand that more. Associate a drive letter with a password and keep that stored somewhere. If the entered password is correct, show that drive as you already have a list/array of them. (note it's too early for me to write this all out and I have a cold - but it's fairly simple).

You have your list of drives, you check a password to see if they can see a drive, if so let them see it.

---

If you are trying to restrict the entire windows system from showing drive letters based on a password, I would say do not use C#. This is a windows security issue.

I would recommend reading abot MS Group Policies. This article can help you:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/231289

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this can be done transparently (you can access the file with any program) and securely (that is, the disk is actually encrypted, not just hidden from the shell) in C# (on Windows, not on [Singularity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singularity_%28operating_system%29)). To decrypt the disk on the fly you need a kernel mode driver. And you can't write that in .NET.

On Linux you might be able to write a [FUSE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace) (usermode) driver in C#+[Mono](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mono_%28software%29).